# SQL Server authentication login issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am running SQL Server 2012, and currently I am logged into it successfully, and am trying to connect to the server on the server management studio. I want the SQL Server authentication, but whenever I attempt to log in, I get the error below:

[Login failed for 'dleathrum'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZApNm.png)

I am using the same login that just got me logged into the server, however I cannot use it for the authentication. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Domain\dleathrum and dleathrum are two different logins. They must both exist in SQL Server, allow you to get in.

Comment: what do you mean by currently logged into successfully but not with SSMS? how did you login successfully?

Comment: I have opened a remote desktop, entered my login credentials to connect, and it opened.  However, when I open the server management studio, it asks for credentials again to connect to the server via SQL Server Authentication, and that is where this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN has all the erro codes for this kind of error, but You need to know the state of the error.

Here is a link with all the possible states:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645917.aspx

Comment: I seem to be having an error of state 0, which is weird because the suggestion from the link you sent me says to contact my server administration because I don't have access to the error, but I am the server admin.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find anything about the state 0 in this error.

Answer (score 0):

In default, only Windows Authentication is enabled on SQL server. Try selecting mixed mode authentication.